# Using usort for custom sorting php array

Tags: php

So I have array with Passive, Q, Q2, W, W2, E, E2, R, R2 and I'd like to be in the order I wrote it in.

```
$SpellTitle = array("Passive", "W", "Q", "Q2", "W2", "R", "E", "E2", "R2");
```

I've read about using usort(), but I don't really understand how to use it.

UPDATE!

$SpellTitle is a dynamic array loaded from database so length will differ and it will be randomly set in that array.

Comment: please elaborate what you have and what you want to achieve with usort()

Comment: @Being Sunny I want the array to be sorted in this order Passive, Q, Q2, W, W2, E, E2, R, R2

Comment: @Higeath 1) Do you have the order of elements in an array? 2) Please add your attempt with `usort()` in the question

Comment: Do you want the array `$SpellTitle` to be in that order? If so just enter it exactly as you wish it to be. i.e. `$SpellTitle = array("Passive", "Q", "Q2", "W", "W2", "E", "E2", "R", "R2");`. There is no 'natural' way of sorting it in the order you wish due to the collation of the character set. Why is it important that `$SpellTitle` is in that order? Do you want to use `$SpellTitle` to order something else?

Comment: @RyanVincent Check my update

Comment: I would manually assign a 'rank' or 'value' for each entry, that indicates whereabouts it is in the list, when the entire is sorted  by 'rank'. i.e. `Passive', `rank` = 1000, 'Q', 'rank = 2000` etc. use `order by rank` when `select` from the database.

Answer (score 0):

`usort` takes a user defined function as a second parameter. That function has to return an integer value of less than zero, zero, or greater than zero. This function has to take two parameters - array values to be compared to each other. If the first value is "lower" than the second, function returns a value less than zero, otherwise greater then zero. If values are equal, function must return zero.

So, If You want to make a custom function that sotrs integer or float values, You could use:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if((float) $a == (float) $b) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return ((float) $a < (float) $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this function and also how the usort works the problem is with making the function itself

Comment: In Your own words: I've read about using usort(), but I don't really understand how to use it.

Comment: if i just wanted the definition/explanation I wouldn't have attached my array and order I would like to get

Comment: Your array's order makes no sense to anyone but You. If You wanted help designing an algorithm for that, that's really a whole other question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

> **asort** - Sort an array and maintain index association.

Example:

```
$SpellTitle = array("Passive", "W", "Q", "Q2", "W2", "R", "E", "E2", "R2");
asort($SpellTitle);
print_r($SpellTitle);
```

output:

```
Array
(
  [6] => E
  [7] => E2
  [0] => Passive
  [2] => Q
  [3] => Q2
  [5] => R
  [8] => R2
  [1] => W
  [4] => W2
)
```

Note that array indices order  was maintained too.
Hope this help.

Comment: It is not in order I was asking for

Comment: @Higeath, I understand the problem  you are facing now. I suggest using categories and subcategories where categories are orders using a criteria  and dynamically order subcategories. This way, if the subcategory length changes, it won't be an issue.